# Number of variables in Z3 statistics

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I've tried to find the number of the variables in Z3 statistics but I couldn't find any indications.Can any one help about which one of the following statistics is number of the variables.

Please note I'm looking for precisely the number of the variables not the number of clauses.

```
(:added-eqs                   9977
 :binary-propagations         9922
 :conflicts                   367
 :decisions                   132793
 :del-clause                  244104
 :final-checks                30
 :lazy-quant-instantiations   334
 :max-generation              11
 :max-memory                  15.36
 :memory                      4.29
 :minimized-lits              2
 :missed-quant-instantiations 49
 :mk-clause                   245835
 :num-allocs                  2987116.00
 :propagations                108837
 :quant-instantiations        124407
 :restarts                    17
 :rlimit-count                13420765)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "variables"? Symbols explicitly declared in the SMT program? If so, use grep. Declared symbols plus instantiated quantified variables? If so, should equivalent instantiations that happen on different paths (disjunctions) be counted each time they happen, or only once?

Answer (score 0):

Z3 doesn't expose number of Boolean variables created during search. 
It could if you move the line:

```
 st.update("mk bool var", m_stats.m_num_mk_bool_var);
```

in the file src/smt/smt_context_pp.cpp from under the comment to above the comment, recompile, etc.